# How to determine whether the sum of a functional series is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Suppose we have a functional series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n n^x}{|x|^n}$$ and need to determine whether its sum is bounded on $x \in (-\infty, -1)$

I think the task doesn't imply to calculate this sum. As I understand if I can show that this series is less than other, easy-to-calculate series (infinite geometric series, for example) then I can conclude that the sum is bounded. But what can I do in order to prove that the sum isn't bounded?

Do you know any tricks for such problems?
Thanks in advance for any hints!

Comment: hint: https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Alternating_series_theorem

Comment: @PeldePinda Thanks a lot